# AdminBundle and I18n forms

Tags: symfony, symfony-sonata

I was wondering if someone managed to add **I18n forms** in the `SonataAdminBundle` to be able to Edit both english fields and other languages fields like we used to do in `Symfony 1.4`.

Our fields are I18n'ed with the `Gedmo Doctrine Extensions`

PS: We are using `Symfony 2.1-DEV`.

Thanks.

Comment: have you managed to generate form through admin bundle? if so could you share the info?

Comment: Yes, sure take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10198946/translatable-entity-and-fonctional-form-for-multiple-translations/10210582#10210582

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[personal translations](http://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/translatable.md#personal-translations) can be used in symfony2 forms I guess including sonata. Using recent [stof extensions bundle](http://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle) from master branch. You will need to configure mapping manually, follow the docs on stof bundle.

By default translatable uses a common table for all translations. Which does not have a direct foreign key constraint. You need to specify the **@Gedmo\TranslationEntity(class="your\personal\translation\entity\class")** class annotation in order to use personal translations.

Comment: Thanks for the lead @gediminas. Due to the lack of example on the web, if we manage to do something, be sure it'll be on our blog. :)