# Translatable Entity and form for multiple translations

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Consider the Category entity and its CategoryTranslation entity from :  http://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/translatable.md#personal-translations

I want to create a form for adding translations easily.

I have a functional solution, which is useful, because partially generic with TranslationType.
But it's restricted to the update.. (-> Abstract class use)

```
class TranslationType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('locale')
            ->add('field')
            ->add('content')
        ;
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions()
    {
        return array(
            'data_class' => 'Gedmo\Translatable\Entity\MappedSuperclass\AbstractPersonalTranslation'
        );
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'translation';
    }
}
```

---

```
class CategoryType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title')
            ->add('description')
            ->add('translations', 'collection', array(
                'type' => new TranslationType()
            ))
        ;
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions()
    {
        return array(
            'data_class' => 'Category'
        );
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'categ';
    }
}
```

Do you see the solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer:

```
class CategoryType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title')
            ->add('description')
            ->add('translations', 'collection', array(
                'type' => new TranslationType(),
                'allow_add' => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
                'options' => array(
                    'data_class' => 'XXX\YYYBundle\Entity\CategoryTranslation'
                )
            ))
        ;
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions()
    {
        return array(
            'data_class' => 'XXX\YYYBundle\Entity\Category'
        );
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'categ';
    }
}
```

I made a dedicated bundle https://github.com/a2lix/TranslationFormBundle for easier use.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write few tricks.

Here's the part of my solution (which was for SonataAdminBundle), https://gist.github.com/2116290
But i didn't manage to make it worked yet. It could really give you a boost.

Let me know if you find something.

Comment: Yes thanks, i had already found your Gist during my google searches...
I'll ask on others websites and take the time to re-investigate.
We keep abreast

Comment: I found the solution during the week if you want.

Comment: Thanks, gedmo send me an email with your solution. Great work mate ;-)

Comment: You're welcome :) It was not difficult in fact.
My post is basic and can easily improve. I have already add an @Assert\Valid for translations object as quick modification.